# How to refresh a page from another page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net

How to refresh a page from another page in asp.net? I have one page called `Common.aspx.` Once I click some button in another page, like `Company.aspx`, should refresh. How can I achieve this?

```
If Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("ReloadPage") Then
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(?,Me.GetType(), "ReloadPage", "ReloadPage();", True)
End If
```

Here's `ReloadPage` function in `company.aspx`. I am writing this code in `Common.aspx`. It is possible to call? What I should write in `?` portion?

Comment: Trying to clarify, you have two windows open and an event on one page in one window should "refresh" the page in another window?

Comment: Yes you are right...Same thing i want to do

Answer (score 1):

You will need Company to poll the server somehow.

This can be done using Ajax and a [Javascript timer.](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers)

First have *Company.aspx* check for a session variable on the server on the javascript timer interval events.  You can do a full Postback if the variable is set to some value you've previously chosen.

Now have *Common.aspx* set that Session variable when you want to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how those pages are related. 
I guess that one of them opened the other, so if common.aspx launches company.aspx then you must get a handle of the opened window (the returned object of window.open)

```
var companyWindow = window.open('company.aspx'...
```

and do

```
companyWindow.location.href = companyWindow.location.href
```

It common is launched by company then use window.opener. But this of course works only if you can control the window.open call. If you can't then you must work on the solution by kervin

Answer (score 0):

for example you have two pages i.e.  **page1.aspx** and **page2.aspx**
and you want refresh **page1.aspx** through **page2.aspx** then

add this code in **page2.aspx** page in aspx region

function RefreshParent() {

            //if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {

                window.opener.location.href = "page1.aspx";

                //self.close(); //code for page2.aspx close
            //}
        }
        window.onbeforeunload = RefreshParent;

and add in **page2.aspx.cs** page, where you want to this activity

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "RefreshParent();", true);

//its work.....

Answer (score -1):

for example you have two pages i.e.  **page1.aspx** and **page2.aspx**
and you want refresh **page1.aspx** through **page2.aspx** then
add this code in **page2.aspx** page in aspx region
**

```
    function RefreshParent() {
        //if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            window.opener.location.href = "page1.aspx";
            //self.close(); //code for page2.aspx close
        //}
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = RefreshParent;

</script>
```

and add in **page2.aspx.cs** page, where you want to this activity ,means in button click or other controls event

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "RefreshParent();", true);
```

//its work.....